# Java JAXB escapar caracteres especiales en hexadecimal

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Estoy tratando de escapar caracteres especiales para un request en XML usando Marshaller de JAXB y necesito que los valores lleguen a destino con el escapeo en hexadecimal.

El problema es que lo hace en decimal, ya probé varios charset y todos los Unicode lo hacen en decimal. La idea es hacer el escapeo directo desde jaxb sin manipulación de strings, o sea, no puedo usar `StringUtils.escape()` o `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()`

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] 
{solicitud.getClass()});
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", true);
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "US-ASCII");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(solicitud, writer);
        String salida = writer.toString();
        Log.info(getClass(), salida);
```

Saludos